# Visual memory leaks option not showing in Xcode toolbar

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8.2

As Xcode 8 release visual memory leaks(debug memory graph) option available in bottom toolbar. **Unfortunately I can't see it in xcode 8.2 version**. Is there any option available in xcode to enable visual memory leaks button ??? For reference I am attaching a screenshot of bottom xcode toolbar.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should plugin the iOS device with iOS 10 and above and then check.